# java - content appropriate data in HashMap

Tags: java, collections

Imagine you have a journal of student evaluations. Each student have some marks of each subject in a journal. I want to store this in `HashMap<>` but I can't figure out why do marks combine.

**In Journal class**:

```
public class Journal {
    private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>> journal = new HashMap<>(); // "Student" -> "Subject", mark[]

    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> journalContainer = new HashMap<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addMark(String student, String subject, int mark) {
        marks.add(mark);
        journalContainer.put(subject, mark);
        journal.put(student, journalContainer);
    }

    public static void outputMarks() {
        for(HashMap.Entry<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>> entry : journal.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

**In Main class**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argc) {
        getJournal().addMark("Alex", "math", 4); // name, subject, mark
        getJournal().addMark("Alex", "math", 2);
        getJournal().addMark("George", "english", 2);
        getJournal().addMark("George", "english", 2);

        Journal.outputMarks();
    }
}
```

So the output is:

```
Alex/{english=[4, 2, 2, 2], math=[4, 2, 2, 2]}
George/{english=[4, 2, 2, 2], math=[4, 2, 2, 2]}
```

But the right output should be:

```
Alex/{math=[4, 2]}
George/{english=[2, 2]}
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Anyone can help?

Comment: Consider using MultiMap from Guava or Apache Commons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a single `marks = new ArrayList<>();` instance that you use as values in all your inner `Map`s, as well as a single `journalContainer = new HashMap<>();` instance that you use as values in your outer `Map`.

I'd remove these two instance variables, and instead use local variables.

You should use distinct `ArrayList`s and inner `HashMap`s as values of your `Map`s:

```
public void addMark(String student, String subject, int mark) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> journalContainer = journal.get(student);
    if (journalContainer == null) {
        journalContainer = new HashMap<>();
        journal.put(student,journalContainer);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> marks = journalContainer.get(subject);
    if (marks == null) {
        marks = new ArrayList<>();
        journalContainer.put(subject, marks);
    }
    marks.add(mark);
}
```

BTW, it doesn't make sense to have an instance method that modifies a static member (the `journal` `Map`). Either make the method static, or make the `Map` non static.

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault about `outputMarks()`. I edit this. Grace to you for your help, you're awesome

Comment: I have one question. How can I remove the mark from journal? I only realized to delete the mark by selected value (e.g 5), but it goes wrong and deletes all marks with selected value. This is another question and if you can answer it, I can ask a new question

Comment: @phen0men Do you mean removing a mark from the ArrayList of a specific student and subject? You can remove it by it's index.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a new Mark, the ArrayList is already allocated in memory, soon it will get all the values ​​that you have already placed regardless of the subject

Before That you will make a validation:

```
public void addMark(String student, String subject, int mark) {
    marks.add(mark);
    journalContainer.put(subject, mark);
    journal.put(student, journalContainer);

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> journalContainer = journal.get(student);

    if(journalContainer == null) {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> journalContainer = new HashMap<>();
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> marks = journalContainer.get(subject);

    if(marks == null) {
        marks = journalContainer.get(subject);
    }  

    marks.add(mark);
    journalContainer.put(subject, mark);
    journal.put(student, journalContainer);
}
```