# java - the best way to store student evaluations in class journal

Tags: java, oop

Imagine you have a journal of student evaluations. Each student have some marks of each subject in a journal in some day. Is there a better way to add mark of student by specific date?

I tried to store this data in `HashMap<Student, HashMap<Subject, ArrayList<Integer>>>` (my previous **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522157/java-content-appropriate-data-in-hashmap)**) but I think this way is  bulky and is not efficient enough.

```
class School {
    private List<Classes> classes;

    ...
}

/**
 * Classes contains data of school classes (students, subjects etc)
 */

class Classes {
    private List<Students> students;
    private List<Subjects> subjects;
    private List<Teachers> teachers;

    ...
}

/** 
 * Class Mark is a collection of student marks
 * Contains Mark, Subject and Date values
 */

class Mark {
    private Date date;

    ...
}
```

Any ideas to store this one more efficient with create/read/update/delete actions? I'll be glad to get tips how do I organize these classes.

Comment: You likely need to do further abstraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is to have Mark class with the following fields:

```
public class Mark {

    private Integer value;
    private Date date;
    private Student student;
    private Subject subject;

    //getters & setters
}
```

This will allow to get all the marks of a concrete student from any `Collection<Mark> marks` using filtering methods (google guave libs provide such an API, with Java 8 it's even easier to do as it is now in `java.util.stream`).

Nevertheless, if you are willing to have your data structure with marks already sorted on a concrete student, I would suggest to implement a backward relation between `Student` and `Mark`:

```
public class Student {

    private Collection<Mark> marks;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Now you operate on `Collection<Student> students` and may get the marks on a concrete student from the collection.

Finally, if you would like to operate on a data structure with marks already sorted by Student and Subject you may use an additional abstraction:

```
public class StudentPerformance {

    private Student student;
    private Map<Subject, List<Mark>> marks; //actually it can be implemented
    //with a class as well but let's leave it as it is
    //for the sake of simplicity of the example

    //setters & getters
}
```

And then store it as a collection: `Collection<StudentPerformance> performances`

The pros for such a solution:

1. Less verbosity in your client code
2. It is more descriptive
3. You use one of the main features of Java - **strong typing**. It means that it is guaranteed in compile time that your client code would not accept anything which is not of type StudentPerformance. And it really helps to avoid bugs in large projects.

Finally, the concrete solution is always dependent on the needs of your application. There is no silver bullet.

Comment: In OO terms, a student *has* Marks. No need for a `StudentPerformance` class, you are now thinking in database design.

Comment: Thanks, I do agree with you. That's even the better solution to hold marks in a variable inside Student. I would edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that use a complex key in a HashMap is a good idea.

I would do something like this:

```
class Evaluation {
    private Subject Subject;
    private Date date;
    private List<Mark> marks;

    //getters & setters
}

class Mark {
    Student student;
    int score;

    //getters & setters
}
```

So now in Classes you will have:

```
class Classes {
    private List<Students> students;
    private List<Subjects> subjects;
    private List<Teachers> teachers;
    private List<Evaluation> evaluations;

    ...
}
```